# Tool recommendation for versioned, permission controlled custom list management

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for a custom list management tool, with the following requirements:

- Custom lists, ability to add new custom fields easily
- Ability to use either predefined set of values (combo box) or free form text/numeric/etc fields
- Ability to validate entered data via regex
- Data in the list is version controlled
- Lists are group/role-based permission controlled (only certain lists can be updated by certain people, certain people can only READ data, but not update, etc)
- Rest web services to update list data

An example of such tool is SharePoint, but I find it very difficult to work with. Looking for something similar in the Linux world.